# Migration CakePHP 2 to 3: Before/after-attribute of save button (form helper)

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

Migrating CakePHP 2.x to 3.x, in submit button CakePHP 2.x have after and before attribute, but that is not working on CakePHP 3.x.

```
<?php
 echo $this->Form->submit(__('Save'), array(
    'div' => 'form-actions',
    'class' => 'btn btn-large btn-primary btn-save',
    'data-loading-text' => 'Please Wait...',
    'after' => '    ' . $this->Html->link(__('Cancel'), array('admin' => true, 'action' => 'index'), array('class' => 'btn btn-large'))
)); ?>
```

Please help me, how to get the after button in submit button using CakePHP 3.x?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a custom `template` when you create your `submit`. To use a custom `template`, you need to use the `FormHelper::input` with `'type' => 'submit'` method instead of the `FormHelper::submit` method.

You want to modify the container template (`submitContainer`) to insert your link (and add the `form-actions` class because the `div` option does not exist in CakePHP 3):

```
$after = $this->Html->link(__('Cancel'), 
    ['admin' => true, 'action' => 'index'], 
    ['class' => 'btn btn-large']
);
$this->Form->input (__('Save'), [
    'type'  => 'submit',
    'class' => 'btn btn-large btn-primary btn-save',
    'data-loading-text' => 'Please Wait...',
    'templates' => [
        'submitContainer' => '<div class="submit form-actions">{{content}}'.$after.'</div>'
    ]
]);
```

There is a way to [add additional template variables](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#adding-additional-template-variables-to-templates) to some containers template (e.g. `inputContainer`), unfortunately as of now (CakePHP 3.1.6) it does not work for the `submitContainer` (this is not really documented, but looking at the source of [`FormHelper`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.1.6/src/View/Helper/FormHelper.php#L1021) you can see that for `submit` input, you never reach [the relevant code](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.1.6/src/View/Helper/FormHelper.php#L1030)).